# open /Users/[user]/.docker/buildx/current: permission denied on macbook?

Tags: docker, macos

I ran the command `docker compose up --build` and it ran normally, then I tried to run it with sudo once.

and since then if I don't use sudo I get this error:

`open /Users/[user]/.docker/buildx/current: permission denied`

Theres apparently a fix by setting `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` before the command but I really want a clean solution.

I have tried restarting my laptop, deleting docker desktop (using an uninstall script I found on stack overflow that apprently didn't uninstall everything). And I still get that error

Comment: When you ran it as root it created the files as `root`.  You can just use the chown command to assign them to you.  `chown -R ~/.docker [your username here]`

Comment: ok i tried that command and i got chown: illegal user name, so i just sudo deleted the .docker directory restarted docker and it worked thanks

Answer (score 128):

As comment by @emadpres, I am sharing here for mac user with auto detecting user:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.docker
```

Comment: This fixed an issue I encountered with a different variant of the error on MacOS:
`ERROR: open /Users/ryan/.docker/buildx/activity/desktop-linux: permission denied`

Comment: this solved the problem for me

Comment: Life saver after way too much Googling - thank you!

Comment: Dude, you rock! Saved me a lot of time with this!

Comment: My docker CLI having `ERROR: open /Users/[user]/.docker/buildx/activity/desktop-linux: permission denied` on build / compose commands all of sudden. After taking hours figuring out what happened I finally find this fix. Appreciated if anyone would able to explain the reason behind instead of just a fix. Thanks in advance.
Docker Desktop: 4.28.0 (139021)
MacOS: 14.3

Comment: @MasterWil maybe you might find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75874653/5305343 and commented by @ lane.maxwell here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75686903/5305343

Answer (score 10):

As commented by @lane.maxwell, you need to update the owner of `~/.docker` directory to your username, using:  `sudo chown -R [user] ~/.docker`

(`-R`: perform the change recursively to subdirectories)